# Avro: ClassCastException while serializing / deserializing a file that contains an Enum value

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, avro

I'm getting the following error when I try to deserialize a previously serialized file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$Zygosity cannot be cast to 
com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity
at com.ssgg.ZygosityTest.deserializeZygosityToAvroStructure(ZygosityTest.java:45)
at com.ssgg.ZygosityTest.main(ZygosityTest.java:30)
```

In order to reproduce the error, the main class is as follows:

```
public class ZygosityTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    String filepath = "/home/XXXX/zygosity.avro";

    /* Populate Zygosity*/
    com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity zygosity = com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity.HET;

    /* Create file serialized */
    createZygositySerialized(zygosity, filepath);

    /* Deserializae file */
    com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity avroZygosityOutput = deserializeZygosityToAvroStructure(filepath);

}

private static com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity deserializeZygosityToAvroStructure(String filepath)
        throws IOException {
    com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity zygosity = null;

    File myFile = new File(filepath);
    DatumReader<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity>(
            com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity.class);
    DataFileReader<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity>(
            myFile, reader);

    while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
        zygosity = dataFileReader.next(zygosity);
    }

    dataFileReader.close();
    return zygosity;
}

private static void createZygositySerialized(com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity zygosity, String filepath)
        throws IOException {
    DatumWriter<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity>(
            com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity.class);
    DataFileWriter<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity> fileWriter = new DataFileWriter<com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity>(
            datumWriter);

    Schema schema = com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$.Zygosity.getClassSchema();

    fileWriter.create(schema, new File(filepath));
    fileWriter.append(zygosity);
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

}

The avro generated enum for Zygosity is as follows:

```
/**
* Autogenerated by Avro
*
* DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY
*/
package com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$;
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public enum Zygosity {
  HOM_REF, HET, HOM_VAR, HEMI, UNK  ;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new     org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"enum\",\"name\":\"Zygosity\",\"namespace\":\"com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.Sample$\",\"symbols\":[\"HOM_REF\",\"HET\",\"HOM_VAR\",\"HEMI\",\"UNK\"]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
```

}

I'm a newbie in Avro, can somebody plese help me to find the problem?
In my project I try to serialize and deserialize a bigger structure, but I have problems with the enums, so I isolated a smaller problem here.
If you need more info I can post it.
Thanks.

Comment: Package paths shouldn't start with capital letters... You should really use the Avro Maven Plugin instead of doing this conversion manually

Comment: You are right, I changed the package paths and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Feel free to show your solution below as an answer since I'm not sure exactly what you changed

Comment: Previously, in the project I was using json. I wanted to user avro, so I used a tool to trasnsform a json-schema file to an avro-schema file. That tool created the namespace for enums with capital letters, i.e "namespace": "com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.BioinfoVariant$". Once I changed that value for "namespace": "com.ssgg.bioinfo.effect.avro" I didn't get the error any more. So you pointed me in the right direction. Please, elaborate an answer and I will vote it as the rignt one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main issue here is that `$` has a special meaning in Java classes, and less important is that package names are typically lowercased.

So, you should at least edit the namespaces to remove the `$`